# Blender 2.82 - Object disappears and reappears when moving the cutter in boolean difference

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I am having a house plan with build up walls. I want to create a animation in which the walls disappear from top to bottom. While still cleaning up the geometry I tried already to cut the geometry in boolean with a big cube down. It works well in the first 10% of the geometry, then the object disappears. After shifting the cube more down the cut object reappears again and everything looks as it should be.
Any idea, what could cause the problem and how to solve. As mentioned, I am still cleaning the model up.

Thanks in advance for your input

JK

Comment: maybe subdivide the cube? If it still doesn't work, share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 0):

I subdivided the cube, but the result was the same. Being new in Blender I saw, when the object disappears while moving the cutter, some small areas marked in orange. I looked into the mesh there and found still some issues with vertices, which needed cleaning. Afterwards the Boolean worked fine throughout the whole movement.